# App Script Converting from Date() to something readable

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok I have a Google Sheet.

I'm writing App Script

This script is pulling out data in a loop about Chromebooks in our GSuite and I can convert the native Long result of **device.autoUpdateExpiration** by using **Date(device.autoUpdateExpiration)** as here:

```
do {
    page = AdminDirectory.Chromeosdevices.list('my_customer', options);

    page.chromeosdevices.forEach(function(device) {
     devices.push([device.deviceId, device.serialNumber, device.orgUnitPath, device.annotatedUser, device.annotatedUser, device.annotatedLocation, device.annotatedAssetId, device.notes, device.model, Date(device.autoUpdateExpiration), device.macAddress, device.model]);
  });
    if (page.nextPageToken){
      options.pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
    }
  } while (page.nextPageToken);
```

But when the script dumps the Chromebook info to cells, the content of **Date(device.autoUpdateExpiration)** is:

**Thu Feb 13 2020 15:10:35 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)**

Two questions:

1. Why isn't this giving me the actual date when the updates expire?
2. How do I convert this to an easy dd/mm/yyyy output?

Comment: What do you mean by "the cell contents"? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Select the date cell> View>Format> dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: You can either format the date in the cell OR use `Utilities.formatDate()` to achieve this.

Comment: @cakeinmilk Can you please clarify your first question? What date were you expecting? Also, as mentioned by TheMaster, your best solution for formatting the date is to just format the cells in the spreadsheet. Second best is to  use [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format).

Comment: It's not giving me the device.autoUpdateExpiration - I'd expect something like Nov 2021 or later. 

I wanted to format the cells programmatically - if after running the function I return to the sheet and format the cell Format - Date - dd/mm/yyyy it doesn't alter the contents.

Comment: @cakeinmilk What's the actual value of `device.autoUpdateExpiration`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date(device.autoUpdateExpiration).toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: Ah this was promising, but gives me a column of Invalid Date - am I missing something?